# Call php function with Jquery in wordpress using xampp

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to do some basic stuff but my php code seems not to be called.

I have a button with an `onclick` event with points to a js function

```
<button type="button" onclick="tryphp()">go!</button>
```

and this is in my index.php file.

Then I have a subfolder called js with inside my js file and the function is as follows

```
function tryphp() {

jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'php/try.php',
        success: function (response) {//response is value returned from php (for your example it's "bye bye"
            alert('success!!!!');
        }
    });

}
```

finally, I have another subfolder "php" with inside my try.php

```
<?php

echo 'hello';

?>
```

I expect the button to fire a "success!!!!" when clicked but nothing happens.
I'm trying to figure out if the error is in the "url" paramether of the ajax call?

The file structure is as below

```
/main/index.php
/main/js/file.js
/main/php/try.php
```

Any help would be great!

Last but not least, my functions.php file is as follows

```
    <?php

function newtheme_script_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/newtheme.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_script('script1',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/newtheme.js', array(), '1.0.0', TRUE);
    wp_enqueue_script('script1',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', array(), '1.0.0', TRUE);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','newtheme_script_enqueue');
```

and inside jquery.js I have downloaded the compressed version of jquery.

thanks in advance!

-----------UPDATE------------
SOLVED!

There were 2 mistakes:

-i did not specify the dependency in the script enqueue

```
wp_enqueue_script('script1',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/newtheme.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', TRUE);
```

-the path to the php file was missing the "template directory" part

Thanks everybody!

Comment: you don't include your file.js or is that newtheme.js? second of all try to change `alert('success!!!!')` to `alert(response)` or even better `console.log(response)` and see what error it shows

Comment: yeah sorry the file is newtheme.js. If I change to console.log(response) it tells me that "jQuery is undefined"! How can i fix that?

Comment: Change `jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'php/try.php',
    success: function (response) {//response is value returned from php (for your example it's "bye bye"
        alert('success!!!!');
    }
});` to `jQuery(function($){
 $.ajax({
     url: 'php/try.php',
     success: function (response) {//response is value returned from php (for your example it's "bye bye"
         alert('success!!!!');
     }
 });
});` otherwise you are not including jQuery the right way

Comment: @lordfoti To avoid confusing enqueuing files put the last `wp_enqueue_script` parameter to `true` so this goes to TOP on `<head>` insteat of footer site. [REFERENCE](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to know that **Wordpress integrate `ajax` as well**.

On file `functions.php` you must have the function that *fires out* results to ajax calls

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

    $whatever += 10;

        echo $whatever;

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

And on your `javascript` file there should be something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var data = {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'whatever': 1234
        };

        // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        });
    });
```

Please read reference at this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) that's made for plugins but works for themes as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a lot of ajax requests, you might want to use something like this to help find problems:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'php/try.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (response) {
         console.log('Success: ' + response);
    },
    error: function (x) {
         //loop though error response
         $.each(x, function(y, z){
              console.log('Error: ' + y + ' ' + z);
         });
    },
});
```

If you have an error somewhere in your php file you should see it after "Success" response in your console.log. If your url is incorrect you should see the error somewhere in the "Error" response - it's usually towards the end of the responses. (Unless you love the sound of your browser's alert, I would give your responses to console.log as the error response will produce quite a few alerts.)